# How to connect two tables in database?

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have a database with 2 tables:

Table **user**:

```
[user_id (pk),username,password,email]
```

and

Table **posts**:

```
[post_id (pk),username_posted,post]
```

I have created a login-registration system with the first table, and I want, when my user logs in, to post a text by pressing a button. In the second table, I want to store the `post_id`, the username of the person who posted, and of course the post he made.
How can i connect these two tables?

Comment: your second table should be [post_id (pk), user_id, post], why create user ids if you don't use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a relational database, rows in two tables are "connected" by storing common values in columns.

```
user:
user_id  username  email
-------  --------  -----
      5  jack      
      6  jim       
      7  johnny               

post:
post_id  post_username  post 
-------  -------------  -------
     11  jack           hi 
     12  jack           whassup
     14  johnny         hey
```

The rows in these two tables are related ("connected") to each other, by the values stored in the `username` column and the `post_username` column.

(We could store the value of the `user_id` column from the `user` table in the `post` table, to the same effect.  But we'll work with the schema you have.)

As an example of how to add a new row to the `post` table and "connect" that to an existing row in the `user` table:

```
 INSERT INTO post (post_id, username, post)
 VALUES (15, 'jim', 'not much');
```

Comment: Going beyond this answer... if we wanted the database to enforce a requirement that a row added to the `post` table must be related to a row in the `user` table, we would use the InnoDB storage engine for both tables, and add a `NOT NULL` constraint on `post_username` column, and we'd add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint... `(post_username)  REFERENCES post (username)`. Underlying all of that is a basic tenet of the relational model: rows are related to each other by storing *common values* in columns.